# The meaning of variable assignment using variable self value in math terms?

Tags: math, iteration, variable-assignment, equation

I wonder how this code statements are understood in math terms ( I need to draw curves and to evaluate some easing logic over time periods using similar concepts).

```
    //example one.
    float x = 3.f;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
         x = x * 4.f;
    }
    //example two.
    float y = 3.f, z;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        //z value is imported from other system.
        y = y * 4,f + z * 5.f; 
    }
```

What is the proper math formula (function) that will give me the same result? In more general sense how iteration using output as input is translated into math equations.

Please note: I used two example not to make two question into one, but rather for the question itself to look for a generic concept that I tried to look for in many sources and found nothing quite relevant unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but one way to look at this is that in the loop you are defining what is called a recurrence equation. Such equations sometimes (maybe not always) have explicit solutions in terms of the number of steps and other factors.

E.g. in the first example, the recurrence is `x[i + 1] = 4 * x[i]`, with `x[0] = 3`. This has the explicit solution `x[i] = 3 * 4^i` where `^` indicates an exponent.

In the second example, the recurrence is `y[i + 1] = 4 * y[i] + 5 * z`, with `y[0] = 3`. The explicit solution is something like `y[i] = 3 * 4^i + (stuff involving i and z)`.

A web search for recurrence equations will find some resources. Further questions probably are better suited for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Last term, I suspect, would be `5*z*(4^(i-1) + 4^(i-2)+...+4^0)`, which is [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and equal to 5*z*(4^i - 1)/(4-1).